# Linq query with outer join doesn't return expected result

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

This is probably something simple but I just can't get it right.
Here is my wiring - Event has many-to-many relationship with rules. Event may or may not have rules. Rules will have its own details. Bottom line, I need an object like this:

> object
>           - event
>           - rule (null)
>           - list of mappings (null)

So, I hardcoded these relationships as following

```
Dim eventList As new List(Of [Event])
eventList.Add(new [Event]() With {.EventId = 1, .ClassId = 1, .TypeId = 1, .EventSequence = 2}) ' this is event without rules
eventList.Add(new [Event]() With {.EventId = 2, .ClassId = 1, .TypeId = 1, .EventSequence = 1})
eventList.Add(new [Event]() With {.EventId = 3, .ClassId = 1, .TypeId = 1, .EventSequence = 3})


Dim ruleEventList As New List(Of RuleEvent)
ruleEventList.Add(new RuleEvent() With {.Id = 1, .EventId = 2, .RuleId = 1})
ruleEventList.Add(new RuleEvent() With {.Id = 2, .EventId = 3, .RuleId = 1})


Dim ruleList As New List(Of Rule)
ruleList.Add(new Rule() With {.Id = 1, .EntityId = 1, .SearchId = 1})


Dim ruleDetailList As New List(Of RuleDetail)
ruleDetailList.Add(new RuleDetail() With {.Id = 1, .RuleId = 1, .Value = "aaa"})
ruleDetailList.Add(new RuleDetail() With {.Id = 2, .RuleId = 1, .Value = "bbb"})
```

This seem to be correct as 2/3 works correctly. But here is LINQ

```
Dim eventRuleDetailList = _
    From ev In eventList
    From re In ruleEventList.Where(Function(r) r.EventId = ev.EventId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    From rule In ruleList.Where(Function(r) re IsNot Nothing AndAlso r.Id = re.RuleId).DefaultIfEmpty()
    From det In ruleDetailList.Where(Function(r) rule IsNot Nothing AndAlso r.RuleId = rule.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
    Group ev, rule, det By ev.EventId, ev.ClassId, ev.TypeId, ev.EventSequence
        Into g = Group
    Order By ClassId, TypeId, EventSequence
    Select New With
        {
            .EventId = EventId,
            .Event = g.First().ev,
            .Rule = g.First().rule,
            .Details = g.Select(Function(itm) itm.det) '<-- This is my glitch 
        }
```

Result seem to be almost correct but with one problem. I seem can't get "Details" right

```
For Each erd In eventRuleDetailList
    Console.WriteLine("Event Id: {0}; Event Seq: {1}; Rule Id: {2}; Details: {3}", 
        erd.EventId, 
        erd.Event.EventSequence, 
        If (erd.Rule Is Nothing,  "No Rules", erd.Rule.Id),
        If (erd.Details Is Nothing,  "No Details",  "Yes Details")
    )

Next
```

Output:

> Event Id: 2; Event Seq: 1; Rule Id: 1;        Details: Yes Details
>   Event Id: 1; Event Seq: 2; Rule Id: No Rules; Details: Yes Details
>   Event Id: 3; Event Seq: 3; Rule Id: 1; Mapped Details: Yes Details

Here is the problem. I do something wrong because `Event Id: 1` should say "No Details". It has "No Rules"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working

Here is the `Select` piece that needs a little of adjustment

```
Select New With
    {
        .EventId = EventId,
        .Event = g.First().ev,
        .Rule = g.First().rule,
        .Details = if(g.First().rule is nothing, nothing, g.Select(Function(itm) itm.det)) 
    }
```

And the output is

> Event Id: 2; Event Seq: 1; Rule Id: 1;        Details: Yes Details
>   Event Id: 1; Event Seq: 2; Rule Id: No Rules; Details: No Details
>   Event Id: 3; Event Seq: 3; Rule Id: 1; Mapped Details: Yes Details

Answer (score 0):

Indicate Details the same way you do Rules:

```
            .Rule = g.First().rule,
            .Details = g.First().det,
```

Comment: In your question, you are treating it as a boolean.  If you need it a different way, you should be clearler in you problem description.  
If you need it as a list, then find a different way to determine it's existance.

Comment: I fixed it - check the answer. Thanks